# Point Coordinates in SHP to CSV

Tags: database, csv, coordinates, shapefile, qgis

I have an shp with ALL countries together.

I tried "shp2text" that did it, only it stoped somewhere in the beginning about letter "I".

Now I'm trying with QGIS that I heard could do it, but it doesn't seem so..

How can I do it?

I dont care if it's in csv or a db file. Just that I will be able to collect the polygons X,Y coordinates. Is it possible with QGIS?

Comment: I'm one step before giving up lol 
Tried everything I found online for hours, still I cannot get the coords from this shp http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php

Answer (score 1):

User ogr2ogr instead of QGIS:

ogr2ogr -f CSV alaska.csv alaska.shp -lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT

This will give you the coordinates of the polygons as Well Known Text (WKT):

```
"POLYGON ((-609587.041217662277631 7642184.568168770521879,
-625107.790384300402366 7640918.446049335412681,
-588062.577403088333085 7649193.995257394388318,
-609587.041217662277631 7642184.568168770521879))",
5,Alaska,1.462410000000000
```

Comment: I'll try that out, thanks gsherman.

PS: it says "POLYGON ((-609587.041217662277631" this number doesnt look like a coord that much